# PHPMailer won't work. I've done what github said but still doesnt work

Tags: php, email

```
    <?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

require_once "E:/wamp64/vendor/autoload.php";



$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mailtrap.io';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Port = 2525;
$mail->Username = '1d0cc54f7f6a43';
$mail->Password = '2489181ecde70b';


$mail->From = "from@yourdomain.com";
$mail->FromName = "Full Name";
$mail->addCC("cc@example.com");
$mail->addBCC("bcc@example.com");
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Subject Text";
$mail->Body = "<i>Mail body in HTML</i>";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";
$mail->send();
```

i use wamp64.
it says undefined namespace 'PHPMailer'
and undefined class for all three of them.
ive installed phpmailer with composer.

Comment: Since you're using composer, you shouldn't require the phpmailer-files manually. That's literally what the `vendor/autoload.php` file does for you.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i still get the same error

Comment: Is phpmailer installed properly and activated in your php.ini, check this https://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php